# Android: When adding several images to a LinearLayout, the last image does not appear

Tags: android

I created a custom adapter that has a linear layout and i am trying to add some images to it dynamically. All images are successfully inserted except for the last one.

EDIT: The last image is added to the LinearLayout but it doesn't appear for some reason!

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater myCustomInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = myCustomInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

    LinearLayout rowWordLayout =(LinearLayout) customView.findViewById(R.id.rowWordID);

    String singleWord = getItem(position);
    String[] characters = singleWord.split("-");

    for(int i=0; i<characters.length; i++){
        String symbol = characters[i];

        ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        image.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(symbol,  "drawable", getPackageName()));

        image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(80,60));
        image.setMaxHeight(20);
        image.setMaxWidth(20);
        image.setClickable(false);

        rowWordLayout.addView(image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this...**

for(int i=0; i<=characters.length; i++)

Comment: I get index out of bounds exception. Actually I tried to insert the last image after the loop and I got an error saying that the image already has a parent which means that it was inserted. But how is it not visible !?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should precise a weigth in your layout param :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater myCustomInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = myCustomInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

    LinearLayout rowWordLayout =(LinearLayout) customView.findViewById(R.id.rowWordID);

    String singleWord = getItem(position);
    String[] characters = singleWord.split("-");

    for(int i=0; i<characters.length; i++){
        String symbol = characters[i];

        ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        image.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(symbol,  "drawable", getPackageName()));

        LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 60, 1f); // Maybe LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT it's more relevant than 60
        image.setLayoutParams(params);

        image.setMaxHeight(20);
        image.setMaxWidth(20);
        image.setClickable(false);

        rowWordLayout.addView(image);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried both 60 and wrap_content but it didn't work :(

Comment: I had another problem. It was my mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I had a problem with the last character and its corresponding image could not be found.